# Rewriting an IOS app already in the store

Tags: ios

I would like to rewrite from scratch an app that is already on app store for building a completely new version.
I would like to create a new xcode project: which are the steps to follow to let the "new" app be the upgrade of "old" app?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The identity of an app is determined by the bundle identifier (`CFBundleIdentifier`) in the Info.plist of the app. As long as you use the same ID and upload it to the store as an update to an existing app (using a higher version) you should be fine.

Comment: What about all the Apple security certificates that are mysteriously created and stored in Keychain and such – Will all that break when rewriting the app with a fresh new Xcode project?

Answer (score 2):

The bundle identifier should definitely be the same, then it will override the old app when you upgrade.

You can change the code as many as you want.

If you are using a database like CoreData or SQLite, you should look into data migration. If you don't do this, the new app will crash when you override it. The user can only delete the app and reinstall to use it. There are a lot of articles about CoreData migration.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Not the bundle name, the bundle identifier.